# Equation of Motion from Lagrangian: Expand the Lagrangian by orders of perturbation to get higher order equation of motion?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory

Just to state this first: I am not asking about higher order derivatives, so no jerk, snap, crackle or pop is involved here. I am asking about higher order perturbative equations of motion from an expanded Lagrangian.

Say, I have a Lagrangian, depending on a scalar field $\phi$ and a metric $g_{ij}$, which I perturb to get
$$
L(\phi,g_{ij}) = L_0 + L_1 + L_2 +...\\
\phi\rightarrow\phi(t)+\delta\phi(t,x,y,z)\\
g_{ij}\rightarrow g_{ij}+\delta g_{ij}
$$
where $L_1$ is of order $\epsilon$, $L_2$ is of order $\epsilon^2$, and so forth, with $\epsilon$ the order of the perturbation.

Now, I would like to derive equations of motion. The background equation of motion is given by the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{\phi}}=0.
$$
But how do I get, say, the first order equations of motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like this question! Let us define $E[\cdot]$ as
$$
E[\cdot] = \left[\frac{\partial \cdot}{\partial q} -\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial \cdot}{\partial \dot q}\right)\right]
$$
Then,
$$
E[L] = E[L_0 + L_1+\dots]
$$
I'm pretty sure its linear operator so I think it will be
$$
E[L] = E[L_0] + E[L_1]+\dots
$$
Separately, your perturbation in $\phi$ will lead to Noether's theorem if you assume it leads to an equivalent action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This seems to give me good results. I am comparing my results using mathematica, where xAct offers some tools to directly derive the EoM from the Lagrangian. To first order, everything I tried agrees, but using your approach, I am missing one single term that comes from $\delta g^\nu_{0;\nu}\phi^{;0}$ and I really do not understand why. Would I have to take the derivative of L1 w.r.t. to something else than just $\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}$?, when I have a perturbed metric? But all other terms related to the metric perturbation are there, which confuses me. :/